# How to Run Multiple Junit Testsuite in different maven projects into single testsuite and run using maven command?

Tags: java, maven, junit

i have multiple maven projects comprising multiple junit testcases in which i want group all testcases into junit testsuite and run all testcases in single suite .Note i  have testsuites in multiple projects.can you help me

Answer (score 0):

*"multiple maven projects [...] group [...] run [...] in single"* cries out for:

- [POM Reference, Aggregation (or Multi-Module)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships)
- [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit): *"Multimodule builds are to be used to group modules together in a single build."*.